# Querying Geonames for Continent Code

Tags: geonames

I'm looking to find out what endpoint and what parameters I'd have to pass to do a search for a continent and obtain results that include the continent code.

For example, if I said to it "North America", I'd like to be able to see in the results "NA".

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you're asking, but it might help lead you towards it. The way to find only continents is to use the search criteria's setFeatureCode("CONT"); and when you're accessing each Toponym in the search results, you need to setStyle(Style.FULL); to be able to see the continent code.